# Toggle HighContrast Theme - windows 10

Tags: autohotkey

I want to be able to toggle the HighContrast Theme in Windows 10, by pressing F1.

The shortcut for toggling the HighContrast Theme in Windows 10 is:

```
Left Alt + Left Shift + Print Screen
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923906.aspx

Here is my script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; Toggle HighContrast Theme: Alt + Shift + PrintScreen
F1::
Send !+{PrintScreen}
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the setting by manually running the .theme file. The problem is that it will open the Settings dialog. This script will run the high contrast 1 theme file, wait for the Settings dialog to open, then close it.

**Edit:** Added code to toggle between two themes

```
hc := false
hctheme := "C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\hc1.theme"
stdtheme := "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\theme1.theme"
; your personalized theme may be in
; C:\Users\{user.name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Custom.theme

F1::
  hc := !hc

  if (hc)
    run %hctheme%
  else
    run %stdtheme%

  WinWait Settings
  WinClose Settings
return
```

Comment: Thanks, it changes the theme, but it is not *toggling* it (as the shortcut mentioned in the question does). Maybe an "IF (hc1.theme is running) {run other.theme} ELSE (run hc1.theme)" would help, but I don't know if that is possible

Comment: Quite easily done. =~) The update assumes that the standard theme is running when your ahk script starts. If it is in high contrast mode, the first time you press F1 it will stay in high contrast mode, then toggle after that.

Answer (score 1):

In testing this, it seems that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> keyboard combo is hooked too low in the OS to be overridden by AutoHotKey to add in the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier before it just goes with the default of taking a screenshot of the active window.  (Looking around the AHK forums, this seems to be the consensus as well.)

I did manage to find some [script suggestions here](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=41224&p=187909), of which this slight modification does work for me on Win10 Pro:

```
F1:: ;toggle high contrast
    vSize := A_PtrSize=8?16:12
    VarSetCapacity(HIGHCONTRAST, vSize, 0)
    NumPut(vSize, &HIGHCONTRAST, 0, "UInt") ;cbSize
    ;SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST := 0x42
    DllCall("user32\SystemParametersInfo", UInt,0x42, UInt,vSize, Ptr,&HIGHCONTRAST, UInt,0)
    vFlags := NumGet(&HIGHCONTRAST, 4, "UInt") ;dwFlags
    ;JEE_Progress(vFlags, 1000)
    if (vFlags & 1) ;HCF_HIGHCONTRASTON := 0x1
        vFlags -= 1
    else
        vFlags += 1
    ;JEE_Progress(vFlags, 1000)
    VarSetCapacity(HIGHCONTRAST, vSize, 0)
    NumPut(vSize, &HIGHCONTRAST, 0, "UInt") ;cbSize
    NumPut(vFlags, &HIGHCONTRAST, 4, "UInt") ;dwFlags
    ;SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST := 0x43
    DllCall("user32\SystemParametersInfo", UInt,0x43, UInt,vSize, Ptr,&HIGHCONTRAST, UInt,0)
return
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well and seems well researched. I'll go with the easier to understand solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
F1::
Send {LAlt down}{LShift down}{PrintScreen}{LAlt Up}{LShift Up}
return
```

From official [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm):

Press use down like : {LWin down} {RWin down}
Release use up like : {LWin up} {RWin up}

Comment: Thanks, but it's only taking screenshots. So it's not toggling the theme.